# QML C++ application crash outside Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, crash, qml, qt5

I am using Qt 5.1.1 with Visual Studio 2012 compiler. I have a Quick 2 application with a c++ backend. When i'm running application in Qt Creator everything looks good. 
But when i'm trying to launch application outside from Qt Creator it crashes.

I have all Qt*.dll 's in my folder, also have D3DCompiler_46.dll.

I tried to access some filed in my QML file from C++ part, and I see that after crash in Visual Studio debugger that the crash look like  null pointer exception.

```
QObject *openButton = instanceRoot->findChild<QObject*>("openFileButton");
openButton->setProperty("enabled",QVariant(enabled));
```

I have all my resources declared in qrc file, and it also included in my .pro file as

```
RESOURCES += res.qrc
```

By [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/resources.html) article that menas, that all my qml files should be emdeded in my exe files. But I think it shouldn't.

How can I find and fix this problem?

UPD:
Here is my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QGuiApplication a(argc, argv);
    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(res);
    QQuickView view;
    Decrypter dec;

    view.rootContext()->setContextProperty("Decrypter", &dec);
    QObject::connect(view.engine(), SIGNAL(quit()), &a, SLOT(quit()));
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/PlayerGUI.qml"));
    view.show();


    QQuickItem *rootObject = view.rootObject();
    Player *player = new Player(rootObject);

    return a.exec();
}
```

UPD2: Two persons from comments were confused by one string of the code:

```
view.engine()->addImportPath("../QtAV/qml/");
```

So, I deleted it, and still have a crash(

Comment: Are you sure all qml files used are bundled? Does it start and look ok if you check openButton for NULL before calling setProperty?

Comment: Please show the line where you load your top level QML item from the qrc. I've seen in the past people sticking everything in a qrc but still actually loading it from the file system through dumb luck. Make sure you're doing something like `QUrl("qrc:/qml/main.qml")`

Comment: 2Frank No, when i skip this code, it looks good in Qt Creator, but when i start standalone application, i see something like 5cm X 5cm gray window.

2ksimons I added my code. Anyway it works fine in Qt Creator. So it should works goot outside.

Comment: If you're putting everything into the qrc, why do you need the import path line? That's the only suspicious thing I see. If you comment that out, does it crash in the same place in creator that it does outside creator?

Comment: 2ksimons this import path is using QtAv 1.3 in my qml file. Just right now i tried to comment 
`view.engine()->addImportPath("../QtAV/qml/");` and app also crashes in the same place when i run it standalone. And worked good when i started it from Qt Creator.

Comment: Confused. Does it crash or show a grey window? Also, don't use paths relative to your working directory, but something like "qrc:/path/to/QtAV/qml" (insert exact path)

Comment: 2Frank It look like a small window, that means that app can't find QML file, but problem is not with QtAV, problem is with my "qrc:/PlayerGUI.qml" file